# How can I change a users profile picture in OS X using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, system-preferences

I have written an AppleScript to grab a users Facebook profile picture (using Curl) store it on their machine and set it as their User Picture in OS X. This picture:
[image]

I am having trouble setting the picture, I've tried

```
tell application "System Events"
    set the picture path of current user to alias downloadedpath
end tell
```

But am having no luck! I am defining the path using colons, an example value of downloadedpath would be "Macintosh HD:Users:jacoblukewood:Desktop:profile.jpg"

How would I use this, I plan to use this on 10.8 and 10.9.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is it failing silently? What actually happens when you run it.

Comment: this seems to fail silently on mavricks and i get missing value when trying to retrieve the current picture path

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on 10.8. It may be a bug in Mavericks. I would file a bug report.

Comment: There is no error produced. I just tried on a friends machine with ML and on running getpupicture path it showed the path I set but did not change the actual picture.

Comment: supposedly under mavericks you can setup your facebook in internet accounts prefs and link the profile pic but i haven't been able to get it working yet

Comment: Neither, thats why I wanted to make the script.

Comment: Any chance your script is open source? Wouldn't mind having a peek!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because you are using Old:Mac:Format for your path, instead of the industry standard path/to/foo (POSIX). Is there any particular reason that you are using Ye Olde Mac Format?

Comment: From memory (this was 1.5 years or so ago) the POSTIX format was not working in AppleScript and you had to use the Silly:Old:Format.

Comment: I saw the date before I posted, but I still thought POSIX was the standard. I think POSIX was used by the OS.